# Formulations for wax thermostatic element for effect in alternative temperature range

Tags: phase, temperature, mechanical-properties

Wax thermostatic elements are used automobile cooling systems and anti-scald mixing valves to control flow rates or to adjust mixing of flow inputs. These devices operate on the principle of thermal expansion of "waxes" to convert heat energy to mechanical energy ([Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wax_thermostatic_element)).  A review of thermostatic mixing valves for sale indicates that the common formulation for the "wax" within the element in those devices expands in the range 20 °C to 50 °C.

Is it possible to formulate a "wax" that effectively changes volume in a lower temperature range such that it could operate a mixing valve, beginning at 5 °C, for instance, or are the materials typically used in this application not effective at temperatures below 20 °C?

Comment: If you read the whole article you linked, it says the range is -15 C to 120 C, so yes, 5 C is within the possible range.

Answer (score 2):

Although typical applications for wax elements are centered around 40 °C, it is possible to create formulations for wax elements that change volume in the lower range of 5 °C to 20 °C.  The example below, although not linear in the lowest temperature extreme of the range of interest, behaves roughly linearly in the majority of the range.

[image: diagram of wax element with stroke versus temperature curve]